# attach hyperlink to dynamic table cell

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in generated using PHP using data collected from MYSQL. How do I append a hyperlink to a row?

Here is the code for the dynamic table I am using:

```
 mydata = mysql_query($sql,$con);

 echo "<table id='name',table border=0>
<tr>
<th>Users</th>
<th>Status<th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $record['user_id'] . "</td>";
if (strtolower(trim($record['activity']))!=strtolower('LOGIN')){ 
echo "<td>" . $default1  . "</td>";
}else{

echo "<td>" . $default  . "</td>";

}

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
;
```

I have tried appending a href="..." style="display:block;"> but cannot get it to work.

Comment: What is this outputting?

Comment: php is irrelevant, its an html issue, and a row cant be a link with out js\css (don't quote me).

Comment: a user table with their status - online or ofline

Comment: Hey john I have tried that but still no luck perhaps I am placing the <a> in the wrong place could you please suggest the correct place to place it. Thanks

Comment: Can you paste some source code of the output? What happenes when you `var_dump($record['user_id'])`? Help us help you. Your question is lacking in details.

Comment: i get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$record' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 29

Comment: Are you missing a `$` in front of `mydata` ? Also, you can't create an object unless you use mysqli or pdo.

Comment: It is impossible for a table cell to be a hyperlink, as a table cell is neither a block or inline element.

Comment: @desbest The link goes inside the cell, obviously. Edit: Actually, upon reflection, I'm not sure the OP realizes this. Also, I pointed out fundamental flaws in his code that he has yet to address.

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing out a hyperlink.

```
echo "<a href='http://www.google.com/'>Google</a>";
```

If you want other functionality, such as clicking on a table row to work as a hyperlink, you would need to implement that in javascript as a table cell/row is not a hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks Johnathon I will bear that in mind I was just trying to replicate this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070232/how-to-make-a-cell-of-table-hyperlink

Comment: That was just an example, you need to replace the URL and text with something appropriate to your application, perhaps coming from the database query.

Comment: The OP needs to address the fact that he can't create an object without mysqli or pdo, as well as missing `$`'s in front of variables.