# Table cell as a link

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table where I want to fix the height to larger than the default value (for aesthetic reasons), the problem is : the links are only active for the text area and not the entire height. I already have it as display: block ...any help?

```
            .myTable {border-collapse: collapse; text-align:center;float:none; 
        border: 10px #ccc solid;
          }
            .myTable td { width:150px ;height:80px;background:#55ddff; }
            .myTable td a {display: block; }
```

and this is the html body:

```
<table class="myTable">
<TR><TD><a href="">hello</a></TD></TR>
<TR><TD><a href="">hello</a></TD></TR>
<TR><TD><a href="">hello</a></TD></TR>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337914/how-to-make-a-td-a-link and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070232/how-to-make-a-cell-of-table-hyperlink

Comment: i dont see what i did wrong to lose reputation !! that question may be close to mine but  the answers were not clear to me ...

Comment: this is outrageous !!! you get punished for asking a question ...wow

Comment: Width 100% and Height 100% are the one missing there and that is what is stated in the answers there. I am not sure, what was not clear to you.

Comment: And even if it wasn't clear, you could have asked your doubts as comments there and I am sure the community would have helped you.

Comment: If you need your reputation back and "if you genuinely think its a duplicate question", you can delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.myTable td a {display:block;width:100%;height:100%;margin:0}
```