# Hyperlink Table Cell Text not Centered

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make an entire cell of my table clickable and I've tried just about every solution I found here except whenever my table cell is finally a hyperlink, the text just will not center no matter what I do and I could use some help.

Here's my html:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

td a {
  color: #333;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">home</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here's the CSS for it:

And here's a visual of what it looks like:

[image]

Sorry if this is something that's been asked and answered, I just personally couldn't find a solution on here after three days of searching. Thanks to anyone that helps!

Comment: Did not understand. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Searching far less than three days got me: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070232/how-to-make-a-cell-of-table-hyperlink), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337914/how-can-i-make-a-link-from-a-td-table-cell) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966027/make-link-in-table-cell-fill-the-entire-row-height/3966257#3966257).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make link in table cell fill the entire row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966027/make-link-in-table-cell-fill-the-entire-row-height)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use flex here. Just set `display:block` to your anchor tag and add some padding for spacing.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

td a {
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">home</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `align-items: center;` in anchor tag

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

td a {
  color: #333;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">home</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

td a, td a:link, td a:hover {
  display:block;
  color: #333;
  padding:40px;
  text-align:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">home</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This should work for you. You don't need to break out the flexbox, and you don't need to make the `td a` width:100% height:100%. If you just set those properties for the `table`, the `td a` will stretch.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

td a{text-align: justify;}