# How to do I get an anchor tag to fill the width of a table cell?

Tags: html, width, anchor

I have a table cell with an anchor tag and I want the width (and height) of the anchor tag to fill the width of the containing table cell. Intuition doesn't seem to work on this. Please help.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="width_is_100px">
            <a href="http://www.doesnotwork.com"><span class="make_width_100px">Some Text</span></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS: (doesn't work)

```
.make_width_100px {
    width:100px !important;
}
```

The anchor tag is only as wide as the text "Some Text". I want the user to be able to click anywhere inside the table cell and trigger the link. No javascript please.

Comment: try using div instead of span. span don't have width and height attributes. set div width to 100% so that it will fill whatever width you set to td.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try it:

```
a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;        
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make your `<a>` element a block element (it's inline by default):

```
.width_is_100px a {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers work properly to fill the width and height [when the text wraps](https://jsfiddle.net/950c1284/).

The only answer I found that produces a proper result filling the height and width of the cell right to the edges is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966027/make-link-in-table-cell-fill-the-entire-row-height#15801081):

```
td {
    overflow: hidden;
}

td > a {
    display: block;
    margin: -10em;
    padding: 10em;
}
```

Comment: It's 2019 and running Firefox Night (67.0a1), this works like a charm! Thanks so much for this and no hackish position-absolute-way as back in the days of IE9 & Co. 

Comment: The only thing that worked for me in Chrome to cover both width and height edge-to-edge.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="width_is_100px">
            <a href="http://www.doesnotwork.com"><div style="width:100%;">Some Text</div></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is probably too late but, this worked for me in tables with different content height.

html

```
<table class="example">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="">small content</a></td>
        <td><a href="">multiline<br>content</a></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

css

```
table{ 
    padding:10px;  /*for example*/
}
table.example td{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0px; /*you can need !important*/
}
table.example a{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 10px 500px 10px; /*table default padding except on bottom 500px for example*/
    margin-bottom: -490px; /*same as bottom padding - table padding*/
}
```