# How Can I Hyperlink to a Specific Table Row

Tags: html

I thought that it would be a simple matter to use a named anchor to Hyperlink to a specific row of a table.  Apparently it's not as easy as I thought. Anyone have any suggestions on how I can accomplish this feat?  Thanks for any input.

Doug

Comment: possible duplicate of [table row as anchor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254860/table-row-as-anchor)

Comment: If the answer provided worked for you, don't forget to accept it (click the checkmark next to it) so that user gets credit for giving a good answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use ids. The `#` sign inside the `href` attribute means the link will go to the same page starting where the id is. You then need to add the same row name to your `tr` element.

```
<a href="#my-row">Go to Row</a>

<tr id="my-row">
```

> Link to a Fragment - link
>   It is often usefull to link to other places on the same webpage, such as other sections or chapters further down the page.
>
> The technical term for this is linking to a Fragment, where browsers will automatically try and scroll to that part of the page.
>
> Fragments first need to be defined somewhere in a webpage by giving them a name, for example , then links to this fragment are created by using the hash (#) character: Link.
>
> To link to a fragment on another page you would simply append the fragment name to the address, for example: href="example.html#fragment_name".

Source: http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/linking.php

Comment: Works great!  Thanks.