# Set empty table cell height 100%

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have a table row that contains 3 `td`s. In the middle `td` there is text, so it has a certain height, e.g. 100px.

The two `td`s on the left and the right contain a table each that display a (later) clickable area which is supposed to have the same height as the middle `td` - so 100px in my example.

Unfortunately, only Firefox stretches the left and right `td`s to 100% height. Chrome, Safari and IE just put it on minium height.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X3YAu/

I've played around with the `display` property but it didn't help. Doesn't the 100% height refer to the parent element and if so why don't the `td`s strech to the 100% height of the parent element?

Comment: why are you using total empty first `<tr>` ?

Comment: please make a fiddle with essential css and HTML.

Comment: @diEcho I know the html looks complicated - and it is, but I already tried to pick only the essentials. The real stuff is much heavier

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/X3YAu/7/

Answer (score 18):

Putting the `&nbsp;` in your empty `<td></td>` should help.

---

**Added info:**

I rewrote entirely your code because you have a lot of useless tags there, this should work:

```
<table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="100%" height="20" colspan="3" bgcolor="#A9DBF5">
            <img src="http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/splashyIcons/arrow_large_up.png" width="16" height="16" title="Up" alt="Arrow up" style="display:inline-block;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="22" height="100">
            <img src="http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/splashyIcons/arrow_large_left.png" width="16" height="16" title="Left" alt="Arrow left" style="display:inline-block;padding:3px;background:#A9DBF5;" />
        </td>
        <td align="left" height="100" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="22" height="100">
            <img src="http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/splashyIcons/arrow_large_right.png" width="16" height="16" title="Right" alt="Arrow right" style="display:inline-block;padding:3px;background:#A9DBF5;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="100%" height="20" colspan="3" bgcolor="#A9DBF5">
            <img src="http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/splashyIcons/arrow_large_down.png" width="16" height="16" title="Down" alt="Arrow down" style="display:inline-block;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you see, instead of using empty `<td>`s , i just put one there with argument `colspan="3"` spread one td entirely on three columns.

Here is a demo: [jsbin LINK](http://jsbin.com/itosow/1/)

Note that, i didn't used `border-radius` and `border` css as you did, to maintain the code as short as possible, so you can get the idea.

Comment: The td is displayed - that's not the problem. The problem is that the height doesn't adjust to 100%...

Comment: ok, your code is written in not the best way, for example you have a lot of empty `td`s in your table, you could use `colspan` attribute to group all of them to one `td`. i'am updating my answer, along with the  `html` code.

Answer (score 9):

Another trick is to use the `:after` pseudo-element:

```
td.empty:after {
  content: 'Empty cell';
  visibility: hidden;
  speak: none;
}
```

This should work in any browser (tested in Chrome on Windows 7) and saves you a lot of `&nbsp;` and separates better presentation from logic.

Answer (score 6):

there is no such thing as `height: 100%.`

A element can never fill its parents height just by passing `height: 100%`, the solutions to add `&nbsp;` or `table {empty-cells: show;}` should do the trick, but without a specific height you never get the desired effect.

Comment: FireFox handles thing the other way like Chrome, Safari or Opera and Internet Explorer does. don't make it a reference if FF does it, and all other browsers don't. like i said: there is no such thing a height: 100%.

Comment: how come it works in Chrome when setting `.ghost.column` to `display: inline-block;`? http://jsfiddle.net/X3YAu/10/

Comment: It's because you are wrong. Of course an element can fill its parent height by passing `height: 100%` http://jsfiddle.net/G8hwd/1/ It would be horrible if it didn't actually...

Comment: okay, thats because you are passing a height in your parent, but in your original problem (to go back to your original issue), you are not passing a height in the parent element (in your jsfiddle), so the child will only take up as much height it needs. and thats what i mean, there is no height: 100% if no height is set

Comment: but in my original problem the table row has a specific height determined by the non-empty table cell in the middle. So the left and right table cells should have the same height as the middle `td` and the parent `tr`. So all I'm trying to do is set the span with the arrow the same height as the `tr` and I don't understand why that shouldn't work with `height: 100%` since the `td` obviously has the right height...

Answer (score 2):

Is it ok to use jQuery in your solution? If so, you could put the following into a function and call it on load, and whenever the table resizes (if it resizes)

```
$('.ghost.column table').height($('.ghost.column').height())
```

I also wonder if using tables is the best approach for your goal? Is there a reason for this, or could it be possible to try using `<div>` elements instead?

Working Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/X3YAu/14/

Answer (score 2):

**To keep empty cell height 100%**

For `<th>` and `<td>` :

```
th:empty::before,td:empty::before{content:'\00a0';visibility:hidden}
```

For `<td>` only :

```
td:empty::before{content:'\00a0';visibility:hidden}
```

Description:

`'\00a0'` is code for single space

`visibility:hidden` to hide that single space

Comment: Very nice! This is the only solution that worked for me, avoiding the superfluous &nbsp; characters of other solutions ...

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use the CSS way.

```
table { empty-cells: show; }
```

The `&nbsp;` way is a good way but it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: Follow the guide featured http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/HTML/emptycells.html for best pratice. As table cells shouldn't really be empty.

Comment: Well the cells aren't really empty there is a `div` and a `span` inside. The `div` is positioned relative and the `span` absolute though

Comment: no it doesn't. the `td` is displayed - that's not the problem. The problem is that the height doesn't adjust to 100%...

Comment: `empty-cells: show` is the default and therefor not worth to be specified.

Comment: Table cells being empty isn't necessarily a bad thing. In true tabular data it is correct and makes sense, and you should allow screen readers to take charge of how they wish to deal with it. But as others have stated, `empty-cells: show` has been default for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966027/make-link-in-table-cell-fill-the-entire-row-height) and it worked. There's no need to put extra spaces for blank cells this way.

```
td a {
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need:

```
table { empty-cells: show; 
min-width: 130px; //example.
}
```

Thats all and it worked for me