# Maintaining href "open in new tab" with an onClick handler in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an onClick (React) handler on a table cell that fires properly, however I want to maintain the "Open in a new Tab" feature that having an `href` on a tag gives you.

Trying to combine both on a single element doesn't work as expected, of course:

```
<td onClick={this.someFunction} href="someLink">
  ...some content
<td>
```

Previously I looked into having an anchor tag nested inside the table cell span the full height, so whenever the contents of the cell were right-clicked, I could "Open in a New Tab" and still keep an `onClick` handler on the table cell element. However there's various problems with that approach, [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966027/make-link-in-table-cell-fill-the-entire-row-height).

**TLDR: Overriding causes other problems. Solutions have various compatibility issues.**

So I ditched that approach for the one explained above. Ideas/suggestions?
Is there a way to have the option "Open in a New Tab" without having to use an anchor/href?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript

Comment: href on a table cell element?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yeah I know how strange that sounds. I was just showing that as an example. Originally it was just an anchor tag with an `href` inside of the table cell, but getting that anchor tag to span the full height does not appear to be a viable option without messing with the positioning.

Answer (score 207):

You have two options here, you can make it open in a new window/tab with JS:

```
<td onClick={()=> window.open("someLink", "_blank")}>text</td>
```

But a better option is to use a regular link but style it as a table cell:

```
<a style={{display: "table-cell"}} href="someLink" target="_blank">text</a>
```

Answer (score 115):

### Most Secure Solution, JS only

As mentioned by alko989, there is a major security flaw with `_blank` ([details here](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/)).

To avoid it from pure JS code:

```js
const openInNewTab = (url) => {
  const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer')
  if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null
}
```

Then add to your `onClick`

```js
onClick={() => openInNewTab('https://stackoverflow.com')}
```

To be even terser in react, you can directly return a function

```js
const onClickUrl = (url) => {
  return () => openInNewTab(url)
}

onClick={onClickUrl('https://stackoverflow.com')}
```

For **Typescript** + **React**, here is what these would look like:

```js
export const openInNewTab = (url: string): void => {
  const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer')
  if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null
}

export const onClickUrl = (url: string): (() => void) => () => openInNewTab(url)
```

The third `window.open` param can also take [these optional values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features), based on your needs.

Comment: What does it do exactly? `if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null` I tried to console.log newWindow but it returns null always.

Comment: I'm not sure which contexts return non-null values, but the spec is to return a window reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: This is the best response

Answer (score 29):

The answer from @gunn is correct, `target="_blank` makes the link open in a new tab.

But this can be a security risk for you page; you can read about it [here](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/). There is a simple solution for that: adding `rel="noopener noreferrer"`.

```
<a style={{display: "table-cell"}} href = "someLink" target = "_blank" 
rel = "noopener noreferrer">text</a>
```

Comment: WHOA, the security issue is BIG

Answer (score 8):

**React + TypeScript** inline util method:

```
const navigateToExternalUrl = (url: string, shouldOpenNewTab: boolean = true) =>
shouldOpenNewTab ? window.open(url, "_blank") : window.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 5):

Above answers are correct. But simply this worked for me

```
target={"_blank"}
```

Comment: This ignores the security issues pointed out in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done. I hope this helps.

link with css gets full width and height.

if statement checks if user is not trying to open new tab by ctrl+click.

You can navigate between links with keyboard as well.

Accessibility:

[Alternatively, you may use the title prop or the aria-label prop.](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/1adec3517fc2c9797212ca4d38858deed917e7be/docs/rules/anchor-has-content.md)

```js
const navigate = function(e){
  if(!e.ctrlKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do your navigation
  }
}
```

```css
td{
  position: relative;
  padding:10px;
}

a{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="return navigate(event)">
            <a href="yourLink" arial-label="your link text" title="your link text" ></a>
             your link text
        </td>
        <td onclick="return navigate(event)">
            <a href="http://url/stuff"  arial-label="your link text 2" title="your link text 2"></a>
             your link text 2 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```