# React: open link in a new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to make it so that when the user clicks my label, it opens up a new tab with the specified URL. It currently is not working. Any ideas what I am doing wrong or need to do in my method?

```
rerouteToGoogle= () => {
    return <Link to="google.com" />

}

<MediaQuery query="(min-width: 550px)">
  <div style={styles.alignText}>
  <Label color='green' basic onClick={this.rerouteToGoogle} >CSV</Label>
  </div>
</MediaQuery>
```

Comment: If you don't wanna use <a> then onClick={ () =>  window.open('www.google.com', '_blank');}

Comment: Hi @Jay266, could you consider accepting the answer if it helped to solve your issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

in your case `rerouteToGoogle` renders a Link component. I believe what you're trying to achieve is opening the new tab link on click, not rendering it.
In this case just change your function to

```
rerouteToGoogle= () => window.open('www.google.com', "_blank")
```

Answer (score 8):

The purpose of [`<Link>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) is to navigate from one route to another inside your React application, e.g. from `/home` to `/about`. If you want to open another site in a new tab, then you are not navigating inside the application and so you can't use `<Link>`.

In your case, a classic `<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">` will work.

So, to solve what you are trying to achieve, the easiest way is to add a `<a>` inside your `<Label>`:

```
<MediaQuery query="(min-width: 550px)">
  <div style={styles.alignText}>
  <Label color='green' basic>
    <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">CSV</a>
  </Label>
  </div>
</MediaQuery>
```

Comment: Great answer, here's an [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046030/maintaining-href-open-in-new-tab-with-an-onclick-handler-in-react) about styling an `<a/>` tag as a table cell fyi.