# How to make Material UI icon to act like anchor tag?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, href

I have this  Icon from material UI, I wish to make it clickable and open a new window to www.linkedin.com

should I use href="Linkedin.com" ? or add onClick ? I wish it to open a new tab/window aswell

Comment: There are many ways. You can also display that icon in a button, And buttons are clickable by their nature. Anyways, if you decide to do some action `onClick` make use of `target=_blank` attribute for showing a new tab like https://stackoverflow.com/q/45046030/4636715

Comment: @vahdet I've seen this solution, but if I use for example www.google.com, I get a new window with localhost.www.google.com, how do I fix it?

Comment: I think you should share your current code and narrow your question to that prefixed-localhost thing. Otherwise, it would become a chat here when we try to solve the problem steo by step. That's for good :)

Comment: Simply wrap your icon within an anchor tag `<a>`.

Comment: @vahdet I simply copied the code you added to the answer :X

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do using Material-UI Icons:

```js
import LinkedInIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LinkedIn';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';

<IconButton aria-label="Linkedin.com" onClick={() => window.open('https://www.Linkedin.com')}>
  <LinkedInIcon fontSize="large" />
</IconButton>
```

To open a new page:

`onClick={() => window.open(newPageUrl, "_blank")}`

To open on the same one:

`onClick={() => window.location.replace(newPageUrl)}`

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-ardinghelli-ub0n9)

Comment: `<IconButton href="https://linkedin.com" />` should work in most use cases. see: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/6243

Answer (score 1):

there is two way which can help you

1. you can use  tag insert icon into  tag and give href="(URL)" as an 
   attribute into  tag
2. you can also use JavaScript onclick function like example below 
   https://www.Linkedin.com=' + this.selectedIndex;"" >

Answer (score 1):

you can use `href` on `Button` or `IconButton`

```
import { Icon, IconButton } from "@mui/material";

          <IconButton href={app.url} aria-label="launch" color="primary" target="_blank">
                    <Icon baseClassName="material-icons" >launch</Icon>
          </IconButton>
```