# Auto open new tab when page is loaded in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, popupwindow

I have a requirement to be implemented where- when the form is loaded, basis one of the attribute which contains a url link - a new browser tab should be auto opened with that url when form is loaded.

So i checked few stakc overflow links and found one solution [Maintaining href "open in new tab" with an onClick handler in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046030/maintaining-href-open-in-new-tab-with-an-onclick-handler-in-react)

```
      const openInNewTab = (url) => {
        const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer')
        if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null
      }


       return (
            <ul>
            {dataset.map((x, id) => (
                <li 
                key={id}
                >
                    <b>{x.split('~')[0]}</b>&ensp;-&ensp;{checkString(x.split('~')[1])}
                    {x.split('~')[0]==='PAGE_URL'  ?  
                        openInNewTab(x.split('~')[1])
                    :
                    <></>
                }
                </li>
               
            ))}
            </ul>
        );
```

So with above code, when my form is loaded, it immediately loads new tab on broswer as expected but the issue here is whenever i try to type in other form questions or click on any button like radio button on that form, everytime it is opening new tab which i don't want. How do i prevent multiple times auto pop up of new tab or is there any other solution? Please help with solution or alternatives.

I mentioned whever i tried in above

Comment: can you provide a working example?

Comment: Okay, I click on "Get tasks" button
It will display the fetch details which has attributes like PAGE_URL(which is one of them) and some form questions on right side.The new tab with url opens up immediately with the details i want to see. Now i go back to my website and want to fill in the form questions. Everytime I click on a raio button in the form or enter a text in the text box, it is opening up that new tab which i dont want. I want it opened up only once when the task is fetched. Is this clear now

Comment: Okay, I click on "Get tasks" button
It will display the fetch details which has attributes like PAGE_URL(which is one of them) and some form questions on right side.The new tab with url opens up immediately with the details i want to see. Now i go back to my website and want to fill in the form questions. Everytime I click on a raio button in the form or enter a text in the text box, it is opening up that new tab which i dont want. I want it opened up only once when the task is fetched. Is this clear now

Comment: I have to see the working example to debug it and give the solution. so it's better if you add a code snippet in your question.

Comment: Yograj, that is the only code i added

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `openInNewTab` function from a useEffect hook. The reason a new tab is opened when ever you type in something in the input field is because react is re-rendering that component due to state changes. Since you want this function to be called only once, you can move the logic of calling this function to a useEffect hook.

Comment: Can you help me with this? Like how will useEffect enable the new tab to be opened only first time and not other times? not at all good with recat

Comment: useEffect with an empty dependency array will be always called once before the component renders. Because of this the openInNewTab function will be called only once.

Comment: let me try ghouse, ill get back to you

Comment: hi ghouse, i added it like this:
`
{obj.split('~')[0]==='LANDING_PAGE_URL'  ?  
                      useEffect(() =>
                        {openInNewTab(obj.split('~')[1])},[]
                      )
                    :
                    <></>
                }
`
But getting error:

 React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks